# Combining different nested monads in for-comprehension

Tags: scala, scalaz

How to combine `Future[A]` and `Future[Option[A]]` in a single `for`-comprehension? The following snippet works but looks ugly, is there a better way?

```
  def getOne: Future[Int] = Future.value(1)

  def getSomeOne: Future[Option[Int]] = Future.value(Some(1))

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val sum = for {
      y <- OptionT(getOne.map(Some(_)).asInstanceOf[Future[Option[Int]]])
      x <- OptionT(getSomeOne)
    } yield x + y

    println(Await.result { sum.run })
  }
```

Comment: What Future are you using? I can't find a method value in `scala.concurrent.Future`.

Comment: `twitter.util.Guture`. Doesn't matter as long there are instances for `Functor` and `Monad`

Comment: No worries, worked around it.

Comment: Personally I have the rule of never using the `Some(...)` constructor, only use the `Option(...)` one.

Comment: @pedrofurla good advice, didn't know there was one.

Comment: I thought it were obvious

Comment: I believe scalaz's syntax sugar `.some` returns an `Option`

Comment: but also (at least in `cats` library) there is a `OptionT.some(getOne)`

Comment: @dk14, yep Scalaz has `.some` that gives back a proper Option[A].

Answer (score 1):

`OptionT(getOne.map(Option(_))` works for me without any casts. The problem with your code is that the type of `Some` is `Some` not Option.

Using Scala's future:

```
scala> :paste
(for {
  y <- OptionT(getOne.map(Option(_)))
  x <- OptionT(getSomeOne)
} yield x + y).run
res14: scala.concurrent.Future[Option[Int]] = List()

scala> Await.result( res14, duration.Duration.Inf)
res16: Option[Int] = Some(2)
```

(no idea why it's printing List() for the unexecuted Future, maybe a repl thing?)

Comment: `point[Option]` works as well. But it turns out that lifting everything to `OptionT` isn't sufficient for a particularly complex for-comprehension I have

Comment: `Some.type` was wrong, this would be the type of companion object.

Comment: I think it is a bit nicer to use provided lifts for that.  
`y <- OptionT.optionTMonadTrans.liftM(getOne)`